# can't reverse reshaped numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I want to reverse reshaped numpy by calling reshape again on the array to reshape it into the original dimensions.

I have an array trian_x with dimensions (x, y, z) then I reshape train_x

```
train_X_1 = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1] * train_X.shape[2])
```

then I want to reverse the reshaped

```
train_X_2 = train_X_1.reshape((train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])
```

when I compare

```
print((train_X_2 == train_X).all())
```

I get **False**

what's wrong with my code? thanks

Comment: Unable to reproduce based on information provided

Comment: Also, I can see at least one unbalanced parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying this:

```
In [184]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                                             
In [185]: x1 = x.reshape(2,12)                                                                         
In [186]: x2 = x1.reshape(2,3,4)                                                                       
In [187]: np.allclose(x,x2)                                                                            
Out[187]: True
```

What's your `dtype`?  `allclose` is better for floats.

```
In [218]: data = np.load('../Downloads/train_X.npy')                                                   
In [219]: data.shape                                                                                   
Out[219]: (97848, 20, 2)
In [220]: data.dtype                                                                                   
Out[220]: dtype('float64')
In [221]: data1 = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1]*data.shape[2])                             
In [222]: data1.shape                                                                                  
Out[222]: (97848, 40)
In [223]: data2 = data1.reshape(data.shape)                                                            
In [224]: data2.shape                                                                                  
Out[224]: (97848, 20, 2)
In [225]: np.allclose(data, data2)                                                                     
Out[225]: False
In [226]: np.max(np.abs(data - data2))                                                                 
Out[226]: nan

In [247]: np.isnan(data).sum()                                                                         
Out[247]: 2514
In [248]: np.isnan(data2).sum()                                                                        
Out[248]: 2514
```

There's your problem - the array contains `nan`, which don't test `==`.  Let's compare without those `nan`:

```
In [251]: np.allclose(np.nan_to_num(data),np.nan_to_num(data2))                                        
Out[251]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried but still got False, can you try my data if you are happy, here is the link for my data that you can download, thanks very much. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/10x9sECTUx4X_BECVlbXviIh02_NGdTQG/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to flatten, then reverse, then reshape.

starting with an array:

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.arange(6).reshape((2,3)) #[[0, 1, 2,], [3, 4, 5]]
```

We can flatten into a 1D array using `ravel`

```
arr = arr.ravel() #[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

We can then reverse the order

```
arr = arr[::-1] #[5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Then we reshape it

```
arr.reshape(2,3) #[[5, 4, 3], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Altogether:

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
arr = arr.ravel()[::-1].reshape(2,3)
print(arr)
```